# How to play Rumba-Flamenco (Spanish rumba) style of music on guitar?

Tags: guitar, technique, fingering, strumming

I want to play the rumba style of flamenco music on my guitar.

What are some defining characteristics of this style of music? Are there particular strumming patterns that define this music?

Which type of guitar is most suited for this style of music?

Comment: I've edited the question in an attempt to make it a bit more answerable.

Comment: The type of guitar that is most suited to this is of course a flamenco guitar. Do you own a flamenco guitar? Do you understand the differences between a flamenco guitar and a classical guitar? You can look these things up.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this youtube...

Acoustic, with nylon strings is recommended...  Steel strings would hurt!

Answer (score 0):

Besides strumming, chords progressions and guitar licks, there's also a little detail that could make your sound closer to the "true thing".

Try this: Detune just a little bit the 3rd string (G in standard tuning, just a few cents). I'm not a flamenco master (in fact I don't play much flamenco), but I grew/live in the south of spain, where flamenco is rooted, and this little trick really makes the difference once you got the other key elements (strumming, finger technique, percussion, chords and licks).

It's a trick I learnt playing with true flamenco guitar players.

Comment: What's the reason to detune the G string?

Comment: I don't think there's one, but all the flamenco guitar players that I know do it, and I know a bunch of them. It's just another spice added to the sound.

Comment: I'm skeptical... : )  Just did a bit of research and it seems there's approximately a hundred (slight exaggeration) different flamenco tunings.  The only reason I could think of to detune that particular string is if it's tuned from bass to treble DADF#BE.  Detuning the F# would give the open major chord a certain instability.  If it were tuned as G it would just sound out of tune.  Tuning issues would crop up for anything played in a different position too.

Comment: You did your research, but I don't need to do it because I live here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusia#Music_of_Andalusia Be skeptical if you want, I just shared a bit of knowledge, take it or forget it xD

Comment: I guess, I would say is, personally I wouldn't just do something without knowing why.  Can you say whether the detune is for a standard tuning?  If it's not, it will definitely have adverse affects for the OP.